# Getting Java to sleep between loops, sleep time designated by command line on Linux

Tags: java, linux, command-line, sleep

I have been assigned on designing a java program on a linux machine that:

1. Connects to a database
2. reads a record
3. retrieve certain information and send to Nagios according to a field known as 'threat_level'
4. read next record and repeat step number 3 until all records have been read

Now, I needed to get this to run every few minutes; so what my partner did was create a script that uses a loop to run the program, sleeps a few minutes, and repeat.

Recently, my boss told us that its good but would like the whole procedure to be completely self contained in java; meaning that it loops and sleeps within java. On top of that, he would like to have the sleep duration be determined by command line each time that the program is run.

I did some research and it seems that using Thread.sleep() is inefficient in certain circumstances and I cannot tell if this is one of them or not. Also, I am still unclear on how to have the sleep time be determined via command line upon running the program. I can provide the code if necessary.

Comment: Why are you concerned about efficiency if you are stopping the entire program for minutes at a time?

Comment: Well it's just a concern I saw a few times while I was researching the process. I still don't have a clear understanding on it.

Comment: If you can find a command in the Java API that is so inefficient that it wastes enough time to be important relative to the few minutes you're sleeping for, I will eat my hat.  I do not have a hat, but I judge such a command to be so unlikely that I am offering to go out, buy a hat, and consume it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` is just fine, especially when you want to sleep for "*few minutes*":

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final int sleepSeconds = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        while(true) {
            //do your job...
            Thread.sleep(sleepSeconds * 1000);
        }
    }

}
```

`Thread.sleep()` might be inefficient or not precise enough in millisecond time ranges, but not in your case. But if you want the process to run in the same frequency (as opposed to with fixed delay), consider:

```
final long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//do your job...
final long runningTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
Thread.sleep(sleepSeconds * 1000 - runningTime);
```

This is important of "*do your job*" part might take significant amount of time and you want the process with exact frequency.

Also for readability consider `TimeUnit` class (uses `Thread.sleep()` underneath):

```
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(sleepSeconds);
```

Comment: This was very helpful and well explained, thank you very much

Comment: I would upvote but I currently don't have enough reputation to do so, Sorry.

Comment: I have been trying to use your suggested method however, I am getting an exception:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
        at SnortMonitor.main(SnortMonitor.java:26)

I am thinking that it is due to the way I enter my argument on the command line but I'm not quite sure. I'm using linux and enter in $5 so that it will run every 5 seconds for testing

Comment: @Pat `java -jar your-app.jar 5` or `java Main 5` should work just fine

Comment: hm, well when I use 5 instead of $5, it says: "javac:invalid flag:5" does it make any difference that I am doing this inside of a script? I can post my script if that would be more helpful.

Comment: ahhh, I see, I was passing the argument during compiling. Seems that I got this working. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `java.util.Concurrent` API, in particular, you may be interested in the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1):

Set a system property on the command line when the program is started: -Dmy.sleep.time=60000
Then get that parameter: long mySleepTime = System.getProperty("my.sleep.time");

Look at the Executor framework. The ScheduledExecutorService has a scheduleWithFixedDelay that will probably do what you want (run your code with a delay in between executions).

Answer (score 0):

When you run something in Java with a command-line arguments, they are stored in the main function's parameter args, as in:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

If you have only the one argument, and it is a number, you can turn it into an integer by using:

```
Integer.parseInt(args[0])
```

Which will return the integer value represented by the String stored as the zero element of the array args.

EDIT: Note that you send command-line arguments when you invoke the Java Virtual Machine with:

```
java MyCompiledFile arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Where MyCompiledFile is the name of the file you want to run, and arg0, arg1, and arg2 (you can have as many arguments as you want) are the Strings that are going into args[0], args[1], and args[2] in the parameter passed to main.  If you have multiple files in multiple directories, you'll need to specify a classpath - a directory which contains all the directories which contain your files.  (Note that these are binary files, the result of compiling source files, not the source files themselves).  In that case, use:

```
java -cp MyClassPath MyCompiledFile arg0 arg1 arg2
```

Where MyClassPath is the Linux classpath (such as /home/usr/bin).

Comment: OK, so when I run the program in linux, I will then enter in the time delay that I want? or is there some bash command that I need to use? Sorry, I'm very new to linux, my partner has been dealing mostly with linux side while I'm trying to soak as much information as I can.

Comment: You enter command line arguments with the command for the program to run; see the edit to my post.

Comment: Ahhh, I see, thankyou, very well explained. However it raises another question. Currently I have a short script called 'testrun' that compiles with all my jar and src files so that I don't need to add each path in. Additionally, I have a script called 'testrun2' that runs it in the same fashion. Is this gonna pose a problem for passing arguments into java? Is there a better way that I should be compiling and running?

Comment: It depends on how the scripting language works.  If there's some way of passing a command directly to the shell, essentially typing "java MyFile arg0 arg1" into the command line without actually typing it yourself, just add the arguments to the command.  If it calls it some other way, there may be another mechanism, but I'm pretty certain that there will be a way to pass in command-line arguments.  It might require some reading on the particular scripting language you use, though.